# Not getting next_max_tag_id for instagram api for user_recent_media

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I m accesing the instagram api for user_recent_media and doing pagination.
but not getting the Data tag and pagination tag in the response.
so the next_max_tag_id is missing.

Can you please suggest where i am going wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate your question with a description of your code, the request and the response. For proper requests, pagination should be accessible in the API response. Although the documentation doesn't mention this, when you use the Instagram gem, the hash returned contains a ``pagination`` item, in addition to the ``data`` item.

Comment: @Dnyan, were you able to solve this? I'm having the same issue. Basically, `next_max_id` and the `pagination` object are not coming back with the response. Only the photo data is coming back. Calling `@results.pagination` raises an error `No method pagination for class array`

Answer (score 0):

See http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ for generic information on the results of endpoints. That page also mentions the pagination attributes that are available... for endpoints that support pagination.